# Recreate my database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I had a functioning ruby on rails app but I  have managed to delete my `config/database.yml` file. It was marked in the `.gitignore` file so I cannot get restore it from github or older commits.  The posgresql database should still be there. How do I recreate the `database.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually recreate it. First use `psql -d postgres`. Then at the command prompt type `\l` which will list out the names of your different databases. Suppose the relevant development one is `app_name_development`. Then type `\q` to exit `psql` and then use `psql app_name_development` to access your development database.  Type `\du`to find out the user role name. Suppose it is `app_name`. Then use a database schema from another app to  insert this information.

Here is an example database.yml from a project (rails 5).

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_production
  username: app_name
  password: <%= ENV['APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```